# How to limit minimum character in selectize tags

Tags: jquery, selectize.js

I want to limit minimum 3 characters for Selectize tags input. Is it possible? is there any event in selectize?

Comment: The [documentation](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md) doesn't appear to have any settings to allow you to amend this behaviour.

Comment: But, Rory is it possible with any other way.?

Comment: Everything is possible. You would probably need to create your own [plugin](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/plugins.md) to achieve it.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem.
Its as Rory has mentioned, via plugins.

Its actually quite simple.

The official example for tag minimum word length filtering you can find [here](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/examples/create-filter.html)

```
$('#select-words-length').selectize({
    create: true,
    createFilter: function(input) { return input.length >= MIN_LENGTH; }
});
```

Another thing that you can do is filter the search itself

```
//restricts the matches to fulfill MIN_SEARCH_LENGTH via the 'score' callback
//see https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md#callbacks
score: function scoreFilter(search) {
    var ignore = search && search.length < MIN_SEARCH_LENGTH;
    var score = this.getScoreFunction(search);
    //the "search" argument is a Search object (see https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md#search).
    return function onScore(item) {
        if (ignore) {
            //If 0, the option is declared not a match.
            return 0;
        } else {
            var result = score(item);
            return result;
        }
    };
},
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: btw why naming anonymous function?

Comment: an anonymous functions has no name. The 'onScore' function has a name (so its not anonymous) that helps a bit to understand what is doing. Maybe the name could be even more accurate, but when you are debugging, you see the names in the stack trace, which is nicer than looking at so many anonymous functions.

Comment: oh....ok......which I never do and think it is not very useful, the object key gives enough hints already. Whatever

Answer (score 2):

There is a working example in [the docs](http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/). See the "Remote Source — Rotten Tomatoes" example. I adapted to something like this:

```
load: function(query, callback) {
    if (!query || query.length < 3) return callback();  // <- this line
    $.ajax({ 
        // ajax options...
```

Comment: This solution works fine. I had it implemented as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a dirty workaround that works for me, hope it helps.

```
var checkLength = function() {
    if (selectize.$control_input.val().length < 3) selectize.close()
};

selectize.on('dropdown_open', checkLength)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another solution if you want to do it with only CSS:

You can use `ch` to set the selection width, which takes into account the number of characters. See this example which results in the image below (tested in Chrome v99)

```
select {
    max-width: 2ch;
    padding-right: 24px;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Maybe you need to adjust the `2ch` to `2.2ch` or something depending on your font.

[image]

Answer (score -7):

1. Download selectize.js plugin
2. Include jquery and

Use this code, It will work.

$('#your-id').selectize({
    maxItems: 3
});

Comment: characters, not items

Comment: there is no direct selectize API for that.