# Minimum length in html select with selectize

Tags: php, jquery

I have a HTML form with a select using selectize tags taking the options from the database, and sending the result in an array to a script via POST:

```
<form action="script-names.php" method="POST">
    <select id="select-names" class="demo-default" name="names[]" multiple placeholder="Search a name">
    <?php
        $conn->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
        $query = "SELECT names.id, names.name FROM names";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $name = $row['name'];
        $id = $row['id'];
        echo "<option value=".$id.">".$name."</option>";
        }
    ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<script>
    $('#select-names').selectize({
    sortField: 'text'
    });
</script>
```

I want to force selectize to begin the search and open the dropdown menu for the options only when the user write at least three letters.

I have seen the post [How to limit minimum character in selectize tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31155089/how-to-limit-minimum-character-in-selectize-tags), but is not the same case.

Do you have any idea how to do that?

N.

Comment: Just FYI, using [tag:javascript] for sanitizing should be used for user-friendliness. It can always be bypassed, so don't trust that data on the server.

Comment: Hi Xorifelse, you are in reason, I a real newie… Do you have any link about sanitizing with javascript that you would recommend?